# Date set from terminal immidiately reverts

Tags: command-line, date

I'm trying to set new date and time via terminal command: `date --set "17 Oct 2015 20:30:00"`. However, it has no effect or reverts back to real time immediately. How do I force date and time to specific value?

I need to go back in time in order to test the script of a web page I develop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is that the time clock updateds automatically when online you can disable time.   "sc config w32time start= disabled"
The. Set time you want
    "date--set day month year time"
Then turn time back on (when done doing whatever)
    "sc config w32time start= demand"